# What are the specific conditions for obtaining a Braytech Schematic?

Tags: destiny-2

I am working on my [Destinations Seal](https://www.light.gg/db/legend/1652422747/seals/2588182977/destinations/) to get the Wayfarer title.

I have one Braytech weapon left to collect. This is the [Niflheim Frost](https://www.light.gg/db/items/1350102270/niflheim-frost/). In order to obtain it, I must get a [Braytech Schematic](https://www.light.gg/db/items/2272569413/braytech-schematic/), which comes from a Sleeper Node, which requires an Override Frequency crafted from Resonant Stems.

I have been farming Resonant Stems and opening Sleeper Nodes for two weeks, and only found one Braytech Schematic.

What are the specific conditions to obtain a Braytech Schematic from a Sleeper Node? Rumours on Reddit are that you have to open a certain number of nodes or that you're limited to one Braytech Schematic a day?

I'd like a definitive answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have done some experiments to speculatively confirm some of the Reddit rumours.

**How many Sleeper Nodes do I need to open to get a Braytech Schematic?**
Between one and four.

**Is the Schematic drop limited to one a day?**
In my tests, yes. Once per daily reset. [Changing in update 2.5.2.2 on Sept 3rd 2019](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/Article/48119)

**Does it matter which nodes I open?**
Nope.

**Does having the weapons you already have make a difference?**
Not for me. I had three weapons in my inventory (AR, Sidearm & Sniper) and got duplicate assault rifles. You're just getting a Warmind Engram, so it's down to RNG.

**Farming**
You'll want to farm around 12 Resonant Stems per daily reset.

**Small sample research data**

- Saturday - Opened three nodes, got a schematic on the third one.
- Sunday - Opened three nodes, got a schematic on the third one.
- Monday 1pm - Opened six nodes and did not get a schematic.
- Monday 6pm (After daily reset) - Opened one node and got a schematic.
- Tuesday 10pm (After daily and weekly reset) - Opened 4 nodes and got a schematic.
- Thursday - Opened one node and got a schematic on the first.
- Friday - Opened three nodes and got a schematic on the third.
- Monday - Opened one node and got a schematic first time.

I have marked this as accepted, because this evening I got a Niflheim Frost to complete my badge.

*[Destiny 2 Update 2.5.2.2](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/Article/48119)*

> Braytech Schematics
>   Braytech Schematics are no longer limited to 1 per day, per account
>   Braytech Schematics have a 25% drop chance when opening any Rasputin Data Cache
>   The four Braytech weapons offered by Ana Bray, and also tied to the Wayfarer seal, now have a greater chance of granting a weapon you do not currently have.

Comment: Would this maybe give me a shot at winter wolf?

Comment: I've opened over 15 sleeper nodes so far and not a single schematic has dropped. I feel like I'm doing something wrong. The sleeper nodes are the same thing as rasputin data caches, right?